# Join 2 equal size arrays to build 1 string array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I would like to join the values of 2 equal sized arrays and build a 3rd array similar to desired array below. Please advice as i am unable to find a javascript built-in method for this. The purpose of building this array is to create an array of custom primary keys.

```
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];

Desired array3 = ['ad', 'be', 'cf']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a basic for loop:

```js
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
const final = []

for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  const curr1 = array1[i];
  const curr2 = array2[i];

  final.push(`${curr1}${curr2}`)
}

console.log(final)
```

Or a one liner:

```js
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
const final = array1.map((val, index) => array1[index] + array2[index])
```

Comment: I liked how you edited your question and stole my work =)

Comment: Sorry? i did not edit the question. Could you pls explain?

Comment: HI @Cyclonecode, I am sorry if it seemed I like copied your work, but truthfully, I did not copy it. I just created the easiest solution first then refactored it.

Comment: I was just kidding although I would not say the first solution is the easiest, more complex and a simple map.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```js
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
const array3 = array1.map((it, i) => it + array2[i])
console.log(array3)
```

The above will map each item in the first array, adding the item at the same index from the second one.